# How to add list of strings to Database C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have list like this:

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

This list contains lets say following names: "Ken", "John", "Tom", etc.

I need to add this list to database table which looks like this:

```
Id          SecondId              Name
1           1                     Ken
2           1                     John
3           2                     Tom
```

Where SecondId is secondary key and that info i already have. But my question is there a better way of adding all names to the database without iterating through list using foreach loop? Any linq query or some other way or i have to iterate through the list to add them to database one by one?

Comment: Have you try Dictionary in c#. Key,Pair value. Put your code here. Because how you know which string value for which secondId.

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi - Basically SecondId will be static for each list. Like for first list if we have 20 names. SecondId will be 1 for example. And for another list if we have 50 names lets say SecondId will be 5. I did not try Dictionary because i am thinking in this scenario List is most appropriate.

Comment: you try umbrella library [http://umbrella.codeplex.com/] it's support LINQ for Lambda Expression.
http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2008/12/15/cs-lamba-foreach-only-on-lists/

Just put your foreach code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to add the list as a chunk.
You could use the `ForEach` extension method on the List like so (assuming you are using a `DbContext` for database access):

```
using (var context = new NameContext()) {
    list.ForEach(i => context.Names.Add(new Name(i, SECOND_ID)));
}
```

You can use the same approach but use you database writing code inside the lambda expression in case you are not using DbContext.